# A Riemann Integrability Question

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Define $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. For any fixed closed interval $[a,b] $,$f(x) $ is $Riemann$ integrable on $[a,b].$**

Show that $\forall a,b;c,d\in\mathbb{R},a<b,c<d.$$\int_{a}^{b}dx\int_{c}^{d}f(x+y)dy=\int_{c}^{d}dy\int_{b}^{a}f(x+y)dx.$

---

If $f (x+y) $ is $Riemann$ integrable on $\mathcal{R}=[a,b]\times [c,d] $,then we can easily  get the equality by applying *Fubini's theorem*.  So the key to this question is to ensure that  $f (x+y) $   is *Riemann integrable* on $[a,b]\times [c,d] $ 
.Let $A= \lbrace (u,v)\in \mathcal {R^{\circ}} \quad |\quad f (x+y) \text{ is discontinuous at } (u,v)\rbrace$,we only need to prove  $A$ has *Lebesgue measure* zero .But how can I prove $m(A)=0$ is  ture?

Comment: Do you mean "proof" or did you mean really mean to say "prove"?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ so what do you mean by "$f(x+y)$ is integrable on $[a,b]\times [c,d]$" (which is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @Math1000: Of course it makes sense: he speaks of the function $(x,y) \mapsto f(x+y)$.

Comment: @AlexM. That isn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Consider the set of discontinuities of $f$ in the interval $[a+c,b+d]$. Cover it by a countable number of intervals whose total length sums to less than $\epsilon$. For each interval $I_j$, consider the set $A_j = \{(u,v): u+v\in I_j\}$. Show that the sum of the areas of the sets $A_j$ is less than some (fixed) multiple of $\epsilon$.

Comment: I am sorry to trouble you.I am failed to prove "the sum of the areas of the sets $A_{j}$ is less than some (fixed) multiple of $\epsilon $." May I have some further hints ?  I find another proof of my question applying the definition of  Riemann integrability  straightforward ,but this proof is not concise.

Comment: Yes, there are definitely more direct routes. Draw a picture. $A_j$ is a region inside the rectangle of the form $r_1<u+v<r_2$, and this has area at most $(r_2-r_1)\max(d-c,b-a)$.